# How to do "show tables as col" alike stuff?

Tags: mysql

```
mysql> show tables;
+----------------+
| Tables_in_test |
+----------------+
| t              |
| t2             |
| test           |
+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> show tables as c;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax;
```

I want to restore the result in column named `c`,but as you see,it's syntax error...

Is there a way to do it at all?

Comment: You want to give aliases to your tables when using show tables? I don't think that works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the information_schema:

```
SELECT 
 table_name AS c 
FROM 
 information_schema.tables
WHERE 
 table_schema = DATABASE()
```